# Data is hidden in view Angular 4

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

i am developing a firebase app. The fetched data is in the DOM, but the li is not showing in load, i've searched in google but i can't figure it out, this is my code:

```
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private db: 
      AngularFireDatabase) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
          this.getOrders();
     }

     getOrders() {
         this.db.list('/orders', { preserveSnapshot: true })
           .subscribe(snapshots => {
             snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
               this.address = snapshot.val().address;
               this.phone = snapshot.val().phone;
               this.nombre = snapshot.val().nombre;
               this.items = snapshot.val().items;
               this.UID = snapshot.key;

          this.servicios.push({
            key: this.UID,
            address: this.address,
            phone: this.phone,
            nombre: this.nombre,
            items: this.items,
            UID: this.UID
          });
        });
      })
  }
```

now in the view the code is a loop

```
<ul *ngIf="servicios" class="orders">
    <li *ngFor="let servicio of servicios">
      <h4>Client: {{ servicio.nombre }}</h4>
      <p>Dirección: {{ servicio.address }}</p>
      <p>Teléfono: {{ servicio.phone }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

data is in the DOM, but is not visible in the screen:

[image]

if i reload, it doesn't display, but if i change of tab and go back to it, the data is displaying, sorry if is a silly question but i can't figure it out, thank you in advance community.

NOTE: the bootstrap tab was tab-pane fade active and it should be tab-pane fade ***in*** active

Comment: There could be a possibility that CSS is messing up..

Comment: it was a class missing from bootstrap, fade in... :/

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking its length

```
<ul *ngIf="servicios.length > 0 " class="orders">
```

Comment: hey thanks for the replay, but the ul is wrapped in a *ngIf already

Comment: update that code too please. if you can create a plunker it will be great.

Comment: hey man, this is embarrassing, sorry for wasting your time, it was from bootstrap, it was missing the fade in class.. sorry about that

Comment: @AndresFelipe so is that fixed? by `fade` what you mean?

Comment: @Vega I'm not getting you. eloborate

Comment: the tab panel has a class named fade in for the active tab, it was missing

Comment: @Aravind, sorry, I posted my comment in a wrong place

Comment: @AndresFelipe that was a silly mistake. anyways. happy to help you